# 2 divs same height: Who can help me fix this (please!)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

So I've tried a lot to adjust the height of div 1 to div 2 (or the other way around). Tried tables , tried javascript (worked but messed up the layout when resizing, see: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X2t8.png)), and a lot more.

So; I have this design and I am trying to make it responsive. That seems to go okay but when i have screen size of >1024px my rightCol2 div is not expanding to the leftCol2 div (and the other way around). I kinda stripped my layout to make it as short and clean as possible and I was wondering if someone could help me out with this one, so that the leftcol2 and rightCol2 div adjust to eachothers heights and the layout keeps beign responsive without any problems. My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/53wn4fzg/ or see it below.

**This cost me a lot of time, your help is soooo greatly appreciated!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{ background:#f6f6f6;}
#mainContent2 {
    clear: left;
    text-align:justify;
}

#container2 {
padding-right:1%; 
width:97%;  
margin: 10px auto;
position: relative;
padding-top: 10px;
max-width: 927px;
}
#leftCol2{  float: left;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    }
#rightCol2{float:right;
width:732px;
background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 480px;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
#footer2 {
    clear: both;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 712px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 195px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    }

#topBar2{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    background: #f7f3f0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height:50px;
}

div#primarycustom{display:none;}
.shadow3 {
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #ccc;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.shadow2, .shadow3 {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ccc;
            }
#logo h1#site-title {margin-left: 10px !important;}
#leftCol2{float:left; margin:10px 0 0 1%; padding:0;
    width:100%;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    }
#rightCol2{float:left;margin:0 0 0 1%; padding:0;
width:100%;
}
#container2 {padding-right:1.7%; width:97%;}
#rightCol2, #leftCol2, #footer2{width:100%; }
div#logo{width:100%; position:relative; top:0; left:0;}
#topBar2{width:100%;}
#footer2 {width:100%;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
margin:10px 0 10px 1%;
padding:10px 0 10px 0;
max-width:none;
float:left;

}
h1#site-title {float:left;}
div#primarycustom { margin:0 0 10px 0;display:block; float:left;}
div#primarycustom div#custom2 { width: 70% ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:block;}
}

</style>


<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if(width <= 1024) {
        $("#container2").each(function() {
        var detach = $(this).find("#leftCol2").detach();
        $(detach).insertAfter($(this).find("#rightCol2"));
        })
    }
    else {
        $("#container2").each(function() {
        var detach = $(this).find("#rightCol2").detach();
        $(detach).insertAfter($(this).find("#leftCol2"));
        })
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div id="container2">
    <div id="logo">
                <h1 id="site-title">
            Here my site title
            </h1>
   <div id="primarycustom" role="complementary">
            <div id="custom2">
          <select style="max-width:100%;" onChange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">

<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2 </option>
</select>

            </div>
        </div><!-- #primary .widget-area --> </div>
                  <div id="leftCol2" class="shadow3">
    <div class="custpad">
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        <p>This sidebar is longer than my mainContent2 div on the right.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="rightCol2" class="shadow3">

        <div id="topBar2">
Slogan
        </div>

        <div id="mainContent2">
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p><p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer.</p>
<p>Here is my main content of my site. The sidebar in this is case is longer(last).</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer2" class="clearfix shadow2">
        <div id="colophon">
            <div id="site-info">
                Here my footer
            </div>

        </div><!-- #colophon -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/cuquso

Parent of the two columns is display:table, the children (immediate) are display:table-cell. The size of the columns is in the min-width media query. Global styles shared by all viewport widths go outside media queries.

**HTML**

```
  <header>header</header>
  
  <div class="page-wrapper">
  
  <aside> sidebar </aside>
  
  <article>
    <p> So I've tried a lot to adjust the height of div 1 to div 2 (or the other way around). Tried tables , tried javascript (worked but messed up the layout when resizing, see: 1), and a lot more. </p>

    <p>So; I have this design and I am trying to make it responsive. That seems to go okay but when i have screen size of >1024px my rightCol2 div is not expanding to the leftCol2 div (and the other way around). I kinda stripped my layout to make it as short and clean as possible and I was wondering if someone could help me out with this one, so that the leftcol2 and rightCol2 div adjust to eachothers heights and the layout keeps beign responsive without any problems. </p>
  </article>
  </div>
  
  <footer>footer</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
header,
footer,
.page-wrapper,
.page-wrapper > aside,
.page-wrapper > article {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.page-wrapper > aside,
.page-wrapper > article {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
}
header, footer {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (min-width:700px) { 
    .page-wrapper,
    header,
    footer{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
    .page-wrapper {
        display: table
    }
    .page-wrapper > aside,
    .page-wrapper > article {
        display: table-cell
    }
    .page-wrapper aside {
        width: 30%
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Let me see if I get you right.. You are suggesting the `display:table` method right? Just like crazymatt? As you can see, i tried that but i wasnt able to make the margin-top work. Any way around this? Thank you!

Comment: yes, you would use other means like duplicating the same structure and having the headline appear to come out of the top or use absolute positioning if it's a single line. This is a complicated thing to style but it's doable. I don't have time. https://jsbin.com/geyuti/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Actually I figured out a fast way, this is an example only, it's very rough and there are no classes. https://jsbin.com/wosura/1/

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Definitely something i can go on with! I was wondering though; now when resizing <700 the sidebar comes first and then the article. To change that around (first article then sidebar) do I need javascript or is there a way around? Also, when I start floating the full height fix is gone, correct? Thank you!

Comment: You can use jQuery if you use this set up since you can't change presentation order without changing it to floats, or you can use jquery and floats. There's a lot of options. Look up "responsive equal height columns jquery" on google there's a script you can play with.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution would be to remove the `float` from the `#leftCol2` and `#rightCol2` and add `display: table-cell` this way the DIVs act like `Table` elements and will compliment each others heights.

You can see your [updated JS.Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/53wn4fzg/2/).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Yeah tried that but the problem is that it will not accept the margin-top.. Couldn't find a way to fix it... Do you know a way around?

Comment: yes easy ;)   http://jsfiddle.net/53wn4fzg/3/ notice how I moved your "shadow" class into the DIV below.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! I was wondering though; when I resize my screen <1024 the leftCol2 div comes first and then the rightCol2 div. To change that around (first article then sidebar) do I need javascript or is there a way around? Also; when floating the full height fix is gone correct?

Comment: When using display:table-cell the DIVs act like the normal Table tags which is why your margin stopped working and why floats do not work. If you want a DIV to be before another one just change the order in the way they appear.

Comment: But how do i change the order? I'd like the sidebar to go below the main content when screen size is <1024. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code there, but my suggestions are this:

1. Investigate [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This is a new spec that does exactly what you're trying to do, but not all browsers support it.
2. Use javascript but update on the window.resize event. I also recommend setting the "min-height" via javascript instead of height, because this will let the element flow naturally if the content is longer than the min-height.

Comment: Hi thank you. I tried to cut the code down as much as possible:) How would I be able to update the js code on a resize? Tried that but wasn't able to accomplish it.. Thanks.